# Converting hexadecimal to IEEE 754

Tags: python, ieee-754

If I use a website like http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to convert the hex string `'424E4B31'` into float32, I get 51.57343.

I need to use Python to convert the string, however, using solutions on StackExchange like:

```
import struct, binascii
hexbytes = b"\x42\x4E\x4B\x31"
struct.unpack('<f',hexbytes)
```

or

```
struct.unpack('f', binascii.unhexlify('424E4B31'))
```

I get 2.9584e-09... why is it different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because endianness is a thing.

```
>>> struct.unpack('>f',hexbytes)
(51.573429107666016,)
```